# Cannot deserialize a 'Guid' from BsonType 'Int32'

Tags: c#, mongodb, guid

I am trying to read a MongoDB document looking like this

```
{
"_id":"a770cf8d-a2ec-45a0-8289-b312c6315997"
"foo1":"value of foo1",
"foo2":"value of foo2"
}
```

I am using the C# driver. The problem is that I get the following error:

```
Cannot deserialize a 'Guid' from BsonType 'Int32'.
```

My C# code looks like this:

```
var myCollection = myDatabase.GetCollection<MyType>(this.collectionName);
List<MyType> myThings = myCollection.Find(Builders<MyType>.Filter.Empty).ToList();
```

MyType looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyType
{
    [DataMember(Name="_id")]
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "foo1")]
    [BsonElement("foo1")]
    public string Foo1{ get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "foo2")]
    [BsonElement("foo2")]
    public string Foo2{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question to answer you.

Comment: Change Guid to string

Comment: @Koderzzzz almost everything is a string in JSON, that wouldn't help at all

Comment: Is it not weird that the error messages references `Int32`? How can `"a770cf8d-a2ec-45a0-8289-b312c6315997"` be considered an integer?

Comment: no replacing Guid with string didn't help

Comment: Why you not use standart `ObjectId` structure for ids field?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about BSON, but I suspect the problem is

```
[BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

It looks like BsonId is probably an Int32... but you have `Id` set to be a `GUID`.

Maybe this will help?

```
[BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(BsonObjectIdGenerator))]
[NonSerialized]
public BsonObjectId _id;
```

Or:

```
[DataMember(Name="_id")]
[BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The problem was that in the document one property was mispelled. So the C# code is correct. The problem was in MongoDB.